# Information-theoretic Diffie-Hellman

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, computability, cr.crypto-security, it.information-theory

The following non-standard description of Diffie-Hellman is entirely my own, by which I mean that I came up with it having not read about it anywhere else beforehand.

In Diffie-Hellman Alice and Bob choose numbers $x$ and $y$ in a fine representation and publish $x$ and $y$ in a coarser form from which they can both determine $xy$ in coarse form. A form is considered coarse if the product of two numbers in the coarse form is (practically) uncomputable, but the product of a number in the coarse form and another number in the fine form is computable.

So is there an information-theoretic analogue? My thoughts are that a number $x \in [0,1] \subset \Bbb R$ can be represented:

- In a fine way using an upper-bound and lower-bound oracle.
- In one coarse form by using an upper-bound oracle.
- In another coarse form by using a lower-bound oracle.

Is there any literature on this?

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no information-theoretic analog that is secure against computationally-unbounded adversaries.

To form an analog, we'd need an injection $\varphi$ that maps $x$ in fine representation to $x$ in coarse representation.  But then Diffie-Hellman involves Alice sending $\varphi(x)$ publicly, and Bob sending $\varphi(y)$ publicly.  An eavesdropper can see $\varphi(x),\varphi(y)$.  Since $\varphi$ is an injection, information-theoretically this reveals $x,y$, which is enough to reveal the negotiated key.

What if we consider a function $\varphi$ that is non-injective?  This doesn't help.  Consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ where $x \sim x'$ if $\varphi(x)=\varphi(x')$, and let $[x]$ be the equivalence class of $x$.  Then for the scheme to work, the negotiated secret has to depend only on $\varphi(x),y$, i.e., only on $[x],y$ (since Bob has to be able to compute it).  Similarly, the negotiated secret has to depend only on $x,[y]$.  It follows that the negotiated secret depends only on $[x],[y]$.  Why?  Let $f(x,y)$ denote the secret negotiated if Alice uses fine value $x$ and Bob uses fine value $y$.  Suppose $x \sim x'$ and $y \sim y'$.  Then since $[x]=[x']$, it follows that $f(x,y)=f(x',y)$ (since $f(x,y)$ depends only on $[x],y$).  Also since $[y]=[y']$, it follows that $f(x',y)=f(x',y')$ (since $f(x,y)$ depends only on $x,[y]$).  Therefore $f(x,y)=f(x',y')$ whenever $x=x'$ and $y=y'$.  In other words, the final negotiated secret depends only on $[x],[y]$.  However, the eavesdropper can observe $\varphi(x),\varphi(y)$, from which $[x],[y]$ are uniquely determined and thus the negotiated secret is uniquely determined and thus information-theoretically cannot be hidden from the eavesdropper.

Public-key exchange can only be secure computationally -- you can't achieve information-theoretically secure public-key exchange.

Comment: In layman's terms what is information theoretic security?

Comment: @Turbo, it means security against a computationally-unbounded adversary (no limits on the amount of computation power that the adversary can bring to bear).

Comment: Sorry could you give an actual modern concrete example for this other than one time pad?

Comment: @Turbo : $\:$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: So you have two extremes. Unbounded capability and polynomial capability of adversaries. In the latter you have a PKC system. How about if adversary has intermediate capability?

Comment: @Turbo : $\:$ See my answer. $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 2):

(This is a response to Turbo that wouldn't fit in a comment.)

An [NP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:N#np) oracle [is enough to break essentially all complexity-based cryptography](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/ug.html), so if public-key cryptography (PKC)
can be secure against polynomially-capable adversaries then $\mathrm{RP} \neq \mathrm{NP}$ (see [definition of $\mathrm{RP}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:R#rp)).
In particular, secure PKC is not *known* to be possible, even just against polynomially capable adversaries.

On the other hand, I think most cryptographers would expect,
if they thought about it, that there is a PKE scheme such that

1. [completeness](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5430/2011sp/TL04.asymmetric.html) holds with certainty, and
2. public keys for the same security parameter $k$ will certainty have the same length, and
3. ciphertexts for the same security parameter $k$ will with certainty give the same value to $\mathrm{length}(\mathrm{ciphertext}) - \mathrm{length}(\mathrm{plaintext})$, and
4. there is a positive real number $\epsilon$ such that even [quantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing) adversaries with $2^{\lceil k^\epsilon\rceil}$ time and $2^{\lceil k^\epsilon\rceil}$ qubits of [advice](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:B#bqpqpoly) cannot distinguish public keys from random strings by more than $2^{-k^\epsilon}$, and
5. there is a positive real number $\epsilon$ such that even quantum adversaries which:

   - have the public key and $2^{\lceil k^\epsilon\rceil}$ time, and
   - $2^{\lceil k^\epsilon \rceil}$ qubits of advice, and
   - can submit $2^{\lceil k^\epsilon\rceil}$ strings to the decryption oracle (which functions just like the in the [IND-CCA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability#Indistinguishability_under_chosen_ciphertext_attack.2Fadaptive_chosen_ciphertext_attack_.28IND-CCA1.2C_IND-CCA2.29) experiment), and
   - can use its responses to choose the plaintext

   cannot distinguish ciphertexts from random strings by more than $2^{-k^\epsilon}$.